# MySQL performance issue for concurrent users

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, mysql-5.7

When I am running a query on MySQL database, it is taking around 3 sec. When we execute the performance testing for 50 concurrent users, then the same query is taking 120 sec.

The query joins multiple tables with an order by clause and a limit condition.

We are using RDS instance (16 GB memory, 4 vCPU).

Can any one suggest how to improve the performance in this case?

Query:

```
SELECT 
    person0_.person_id AS person_i1_131_,
    person0_.uuid AS uuid2_131_,
    person0_.gender AS gender3_131_

    CASE
        WHEN
            EXISTS( SELECT * FROM patient p WHERE p.patient_id = person0_.person_id)
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS formula1_,
    CASE
        WHEN person0_1_.patient_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1
        WHEN person0_.person_id IS NOT NULL THEN 0
    END AS clazz_
FROM
    person person0_
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    patient person0_1_ ON person0_.person_id = person0_1_.patient_id
        INNER JOIN
    person_attribute attributes1_ ON person0_.person_id = attributes1_.person_id
        CROSS JOIN
    person_attribute_type personattr2_
WHERE
    attributes1_.person_attribute_type_id = personattr2_.person_attribute_type_id
        AND personattr2_.name = 'PersonImageAttribute'
        AND (person0_.person_id IN (SELECT 
            person3_.person_id
        FROM
            person person3_
                INNER JOIN
            person_attribute attributes4_ ON person3_.person_id = attributes4_.person_id
                CROSS JOIN
            person_attribute_type personattr5_
        WHERE
            attributes4_.person_attribute_type_id = personattr5_.person_attribute_type_id
                AND personattr5_.name = 'LocationAttribute'
                AND (attributes4_.value IN ('d31fe20e-6736-42ff-a3ed-b3e622e80842'))))
ORDER BY person0_1_.date_changed , person0_1_.patient_id
LIMIT 25
```

**Plan**
[image]

Comment: provide a syntax of your query to solve your issues

Comment: Please provide more information, execution plan , query, table info & indexes

Comment: I have attached the query and execution plan. The query was generated by hibernate

Comment: It takes 3 minutes without concurrent users and 2 minutes with concurrent users?

Comment: Get more concurrent users online, pretty soon the query will take 0 seconds! (j/k)

Comment: Sorry it was a type and I have corrected it

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be some redundant query components, and what does not appear to be a proper context of CROSSS-JOIN when you have relation on specific patient and/or attribute info.

Your query getting the "clazz_" is based on a patient_id NOT NULL, but then again a person_id not null.  Under what condition, would the person_id coming from the person table EVER be null.  That sounds like a KEY ID and would NEVER be null, so why test for that.  It seems like that is a duplicate field and in-essence is just the condition of a person actually being a patient vs not.

This query SHOULD get the same results otherwise and suggest the following specific indexes are available including

```
table                  index
person                 ( person_id )
person_attribute       ( person_id, person_attribute_type_id )
person_attribute_type  ( person_attribute_type_id, name )
patient                ( patient_id )


select
        p1.person_id AS person_i1_131_,
        p1.uuid AS uuid2_131_,
        p1.gender AS gender3_131_,
        CASE WHEN p2.patient_id IS NULL
            then 0 else 1 end formula1_,
        -- appears to be a redunant result, just trying to qualify
        -- some specific column value for later calculations.
        CASE WHEN p2.patient_id IS NULL 
            THEN 0 else 1 end clazz_
    from
        -- pre-get only those people based on the P4 attribute in question
        -- and attribute type of location.  Get small list vs everything else
        ( SELECT distinct
                pa.person_id
            FROM
                person_attribute pa
                    JOIN person_attribute_type pat
                        on pa.person_attribute_type_id = pat.person_attribute_type_id
                        AND pat.name = 'LocationAttribute'
            WHERE
                pa.value = 'd31fe20e-6736-42ff-a3ed-b3e622e80842' ) PQ

            join person p1
                on PQ.person_id = p1.person_id

                LEFT JOIN patient p2 
                    ON p1.person_id = p2.patient_id

                JOIN person_attribute pa1 
                    ON p1.person_id = pa1.person_id
                    JOIN person_attribute_type pat1
                        on pa1.person_attribute_type_id = pat1.person_attribute_type_id
                        AND pat1.name = 'PersonImageAttribute'
    order by
        p2.date_changed, 
        p2.patient_id
    LIMIT 
        25
```

Finally, your query does an order by the date_changed and patient id which is based on the PATIENT table data having been changed.  If that table is a left-join, you may have a bunch of PERSON records that are not patients and thus may not get
the expected records you really intent.  So, just some personal review of what is presented in the question.

Comment: thanks for replying. When the order by clause is removed the query is executing in 0.3 sec and when I include it is taking 1.5 sec. I have created a composite index (date_changed,patient_id) but in execution plan, tmp table, file sort is present. It is not considering the index.

Comment: @Nagesh, the PROBABLE reason for no optimization on the order-by is that your LEFT JOIN to the patient table is not required for the result set and thus null possibilities.  But if the query takes your 120 second down to 1.5, I would suspect that this solution IS working for you all-else considered?

Comment: The query is still taking 120 sec when we run performance test for 250 concurrent users. It takes 1.5 sec when the query executed for single user

Comment: @Nagesh, from the inner alias PQ query in the from clause... for the single pa.value = guid, how many records does THAT one query return, and how long for that while concurrent load is going on.

Comment: it has 200K records. Concurrent users load will go around 8 hours

Comment: @Nagesh, how many for just the PatientAttribute for just the LocationAttribute and also just the PersonImageAttribute respectively.   Any why looking for EVERYONE regardless of being a patient if your order by is based on a patient date change input vs all others who are NOT patients.

Comment: person_attribute count - 1.6M records, PersonImageAttribute and LocationAttribute 200K each

Answer (score 0):

Speeding up the query is the best hope for handling more connections.

A simplification (but no speed difference), since TRUE=1 and FALSE=0:

```
CASE WHERE (boolean_expression) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

-->

```
(boolean_expression)
```

Index suggestions:

```
person:  INDEX(patient_id, date_changed)
person_attribute:  INDEX(person_attribute_type_id, person_id)
person_attribute:  INDEX(person_attribute_type_id, value, person_id)
person_attribute_type:  INDEX(person_attribute_type_id, name)
```

If `value` is of type `TEXT`, then that cannot be used in an index.

Assuming that `person` has `PRIMARY KEY(person_id)` and `patient` -- `patient_id`, I have no extra recommendations for them.

The Entity-Attribute-Value schema pattern, which this seems to be, is hard to optimize when there are a large number of rows.  Sorry.

The `CROSS JOIN` seems to be just an `INNER JOIN`, but with the condition in the `WHERE` instead of in `ON`, where it belongs.

`person0_1_.patient_id` can be `NULL` because of the `LEFT JOIN`, but I don't see how `person0_.person_id` can be `NULL`.  Please check your logic.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Value is a text field and a not null field. The query was generated by hibernate framework so there are cross joins and some other conditions etc